# Is it possible to prompt the user for information in a Visual Studio template?

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2005, itemtemplate

Is it possible to prompt the user for more than just a file name when they create a new item from a Visual Studio 2005 template? It would be nice to have more than just the class's name filled in when a template is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the only way to accomplish this is by creating a WizardExtension (compile a DLL with a class that implements IWizard), and referencing it in the VSTEMPLATE file.